# Can't login to Magento Connect Manager - 1.6

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I've been struggling with this issue for 2 days. I triyed everything I found on Google but still can't access. I get this message

> ERROR 500 - Internal Server Error
>   The following error occurred
>   The requested URL caused an internal server error

I changed folders and files permissions but it won't go away and I find nothing in the log files.
Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: The http server has its own log files, 500 errors get logged there, not in Magento's log files. You will access the http server logs through cPanel/WHM if that's what your hosting service provides. Otherwise ask your hosting provider to check the log for the cause of the error.

Comment: Thanks @FiascoLabs. I checked on the server log files but found nothing related to my issue. I'm a little bit lost, I just don't know where to search.